# Angular + Nodejs error CORS

Tags: nodejs, angular, cors

**empleados-crear.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Empleado } from '../modelo-de-datos/empleados';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { EmpleadoServiceService } from '../servicios/empleado-service.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-empleados-crear',
  templateUrl: './empleados-crear.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empleados-crear.component.css'],
  providers:[EmpleadoServiceService]
})
export class EmpleadosCrearComponent implements OnInit {

  public a:number;
  public empleado_nuevo:Empleado;
  public fecha_nacimiento:Date;

  constructor(
    private empleadoService:EmpleadoServiceService

  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fecha_nacimiento = new Date();


    this.empleado_nuevo = new Empleado('','','','',0,this.fecha_nacimiento);
   }

   limpiarFormulario(form?:NgForm){
    this.empleado_nuevo = new Empleado('','','','',0,this.fecha_nacimiento);
   }

   insertarEmpleado(){
    console.log(this.empleado_nuevo);
    //console.log(form.value)
    this.empleadoService.addEmpleado(this.empleado_nuevo).subscribe(
      res=>{
        console.log(res);
        },
        error=>{
          console.log(error);
        }
    );

   }

}
```

**empleado-service.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Empleado } from '../modelo-de-datos/empleados';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EmpleadoServiceService {

  private empleado: Empleado;
  private empleados: Empleado[];
  //readonly url_api = 'localhost:3000/getEmpleados';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }


  getEmpleados() {
    return this.http.get('localhost:3000/getEmpleados').subscribe(
      res=>{
        console.log(res);
      },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  addEmpleado(empleado_nuevo: Empleado){
      return this.http.post('localhost:3000/addEmpleado',empleado_nuevo);

  }

}
```

---

**Consola Chrome**

```
Empleado {dni: "66666666Z", nombre: "Luis", apellidos: "Rodriguez Guzman", departamento: "Prestamatica", sueldo: 12300, …}
apellidos: "Rodriguez Guzman"
departamento: "Prestamatica"
dni: "66666666Z"
fecha_nacimiento: "2018-11-08"
nombre: "Luis"
sueldo: 12300
__proto__: Object
zone.js:2969 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/addEmpleado' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
empleados-crear.component.ts:46 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: null
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

**Consola Firefox**

​

```
error: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
​
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: "Unknown Error"
​
url: null
​
<prototype>: Object { constructor: HttpErrorResponse()
 }
```

**index.js de mi servidor en nodejs**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const {mongoose} = require('./database');

//settings
app.set('port',3000);


//middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());

    app.use(cors({
        origin:'http://localhost:4200'
    }));



    //CORS -2 
    /*
   const corsOptions = {
    origin: [process.env.URL, 'http://localhost:4200']
  }
  */
  app.use(cors(corsOptions))
  app.options('*', cors(corsOptions))

  //FIN CORS 2

//routes
app.use(require('./routes/empleado.routes'));

//starting server
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('Servidor en el puerto '+app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Hola jose angel, debes ser más específico: ¿cuál es el problema que te estás encontrando? ¿cuál es el código que tienes y que genera estos logs? (incluye los dominios relacionados si es importante para entender la pregunta). Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro se consideran de baja calidad. Debes editarla para añadir esa información adicional. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve]. Saludos.

Comment: He añadido esta informacion adicional que resultara de ayuda. Añadir tmabien que desde el postman he verificado que el backend cumple su funcion ( la Api que he creado)

Comment: El error está en que estás intentando acceder a localhost:3000 desde localhost:2400, esa información debería aparecer en la pregunta porque es el verdadero problema. Además, [ya se han realizado preguntas como ésta en el sitio y tienen respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Access-Control-Allow-Origin+angular), ¿has probado lo que se sugiere en las mismas? ¿cómo no te ha funcionado?

Comment: claro vamos a ver, mi app esta dividaida en 2 carpetas, backend y frontend, desde el backend intento hacer una peticion aajax a mi propio backend, con 2 "ips" diferentes

Comment: ponele explícito el protocolo a `this.http.get('localhost` sino no sabe que protocolo comparar (http/https/data)

Comment: pero eso lo tengo puesto no ? fijate bien

Comment: en la linea `return this.http.get('localhost:3000/getEmpleados')` pareciera estar faltando.

Comment: Onda debería leerse `return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/getEmpleados')`. Y ahí el sistema ya sabe que tiene que comparar `http://` con `http://`, `localhost` con `localhost` y `:2400` con `:3000`; protocolo, servidor, puerto aplicar CORS y autorizar o no el acceso.

Answer (score 3):

Finalmente los errores eran que en mi servicio del frontend (angular) , concretamente e

```
n  **empleado-service.service.ts** mis peticiones http estaban asi : 


  getEmpleados() {
    return this.http.get('localhost:3000/getEmpleados');
  }

  addEmpleado(empleado_nuevo: Empleado){
      return this.http.post('localhost:3000/addEmpleado',empleado_nuevo);

  }
```

En vez de asi:

```
  getEmpleados() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/getEmpleados');
  }

  addEmpleado(empleado_nuevo: Empleado){
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/addEmpleado',empleado_nuevo);

  }
```

**A los metodos post y get he tenido que añadirles el 'http://' antes de poner la url del servidor**

Gracias a todos de verdad

Comment: Podrías haber puesto sencillamente `'/getEmpleados'` y funcionaría